# How to get the newly entered text in the TextChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textchanged

I'm doing a page navigation control. After typing a new number in text box and Enter,

```
void pageNoTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The above event is called.But I am still getting the old text from the text box in the following statement

```
newPageNumber = Int32.Parse(pageNoTextBox.Text.Trim());
```

for example if the textbox had `1` and and I entered `12`, what I am getting is `1` in the `TextChanged` event where as javascript returns new value.

```
<asp:TextBox ReadOnly="false" CssClass="txtfld_s"  ForeColor="white" ID="pageNoTextBox" runat="server" Text="" AutoPostBack="true"  CausesValidation="True" OnTextChanged="pageNoTextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is the text box. Is there any way to get the newly entered text using C#?

Comment: your code is working for me, just I need to hit a enter after changing the text

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this will do the thing you want.

```
private void pageNoTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
    if(textbox != null)
    {
      string theText = textbox.Text;
    }
}
```